# asp.net Configuration Error on host

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, configuration, hosting

I uploaded my asp.net site to hosting site , and my site browse correctly . But when I go to `login` url , it's show me the error

> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file       required      to service this
>   request. Please review the specific error details  below and modify
>   your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as 
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be  caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
 Line 23:       </assemblies>
 Line 24:     </compilation>
 Line 25:     <authentication mode="Forms">
 Line 26:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
 Line 27:     </authentication>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You need to set the virtual directory as an application using your hosting control panel. Did you do so?

Comment: i use `ixwebhosting` ,but I can't find location to set it !

Comment: You can contact their support to make them set this virtual folder as an application. They should help you in that.

Comment: Also, maybe they don't support hosting ASP.NET web applications. You need to check.

Comment: They support ASP.NET web applications mohammedn :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the following:

1. You should set the virtual directory as an application using your hosting control panel.
2. Make sure that you only have one web.config in your web hosting directory.
3. Make sure that the web.config contains the minimal sections required to run the application. Some hosting services restore the web configurations in the web.config global file, having the same sections in your web application web.config file can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of not recognizing the access level hierarchy of your website for authenticated users. You can try specifying the location path tags and authorization, as following e.g. :-

```
<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="administrators" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Also don't forget to keep the "~/Account/Login.aspx" open for anonymous access. So keep it in separate directory which doesn't have access restrictions.